# Use mkdir and then put files in the folder

Tags: php, directory, mkdir

I have a website where users can create new "topics." Each topic has a folder (example: www.example.com/chemistry). I use mkdir() to create a new folder, but after it's created how can i put files in the folder so that when someone goes to the chemistry folder there's something to view?  Since I haven't found much information on how to do this im guessing there is a more popular way.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a CMS? Then making actual physical folders is not really the way to go.

Comment: `index.html` and `index.php` are typically default supported, so you could create a file for that directory with a "Hullo Wurld"-type message (or something more appropriate). Or you could use Drupal's taxonomy or whatnot.

Comment: @deceze is SO useing a CMS?  becasue when i asked this question a "folder" appeared in the URL with my question ID.  if that is a CMS could you provide a link to some more information?

Comment: Its probably not a real folder, but rather a dynamic URL, go and google "ModRewrite" or "Dynamic URLS"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is SO useing a CMS? becasue when i asked this question a "folder" appeared in the URL with my question ID.

What appears in the URL here is a ***URL***. Repeat after me: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774143/use-mdir-and-then-put-files-in-the-folder` is a URL! It has a hostname, it has a path, it may have query parameters. It does not have *"folders"*!

By default, in many web servers, a URL is mapped to a folder on the hard drive. But that's just one way to do it. When visiting a URL, the web server just receives the request *"give me whatever site there is at URL `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774143/use-mdir-and-then-put-files-in-the-folder`"*. The web server may choose to answer this by looking into a folder whose name matches the URL. Or it may simply invoke a program, give it the URL and deliver back whatever response the program happens to spit out.

Try to learn about "URL rewriting" and "pretty URLs" and look into existing frameworks, since pretty much all frameworks implement this.

Comment: Yes, `mod_rewrite` is the usual way to go under the Apache web server.

Answer (score 1):

you can copy files:

```
copy($source, $desitination);
```

Upload files: see [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file)

Write files: see [fwrite](http://php.net/fwrite)

PS. Just check if the folder exists first, eg `if (file_exists($dir))` before calling mkdir($dir) or you will get warnings, or suppress mkdir() like this @mkdir() to silence any warnings

Comment: the copy function only lets you add files to other files.  it doesnt let you add files to directories

Comment: @user `copy('foo', 'bar/foo')` There, I copied a file into a directory.

Comment: What? copy() function copies a file to a destination within any directory, as long as the directory has write permissions, but that's a different topic together

Answer (score 0):

Look at that : http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php
By changing your directory you could display the content of the folder to your user.

Answer (score 0):

use **copy** function

```
  copy($source, $dest);
```

I don't know if this is what you meant